# click event on div and filter vuex data --vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am stuck at this very point: exporting filter function and using it in vuex store. No problem'till here. Now am trying to put `@click` event on  divs. And when I click, for example. Audi the filter needs to show just "audi" And if I click "audi" again then it needs remove it from the filter.

Here is the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/filtering-bzphi

**filter.js**

```
export const carFilter = car => allcars => {
      if (car.length > 0) {
        if (allcars.name.includes(car)) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    };
```

**Store**

```
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cars: [
      { name: "AUDI" },
      { name: "BMW" },
      { name: "MERCEDES" },
      { name: "HONDA" },
      { name: "TOYOTA" }
    ],
    carBrand: []
  },
  mutations: {
    updateCarsFilter(state, carBrand) {
      state.carBrand = carBrand;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    filteredCars: state => {
      return state.cars.filter(carFilter(state.carBrand));
    }
  }
});
```

and **App.js**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="boxes" :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in cars">{{item.name}}</div>
    <List/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import List from "./List.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    List
  },
  computed: {
    selectBrand: {
      set(val) {
        this.$store.commit("updateCarsFilter", val);
      },
      get() {
        return this.$store.state.carBrand;
      }
    },
    cars() {
      return this.$store.getters.filteredCars;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I also created a sandbox for this. You can check it for better understanding. https://codesandbox.io/s/filtering-bzphi

Comment: Why is `carBrand` an array by default? Where is `searchText` used?

Comment: @Phil actually I changed it to `selectBrand` now, I am sorry for the misleading.  it's array by default, because, I am trying to select brand name, and putting it in array, not searching by the text. Select or unselect... But this is where I am stuck. What kind of method should I write and select, unselect the brand by index...

Comment: @Phil Additionally, i can do this using `<select>` by easily but trying to do it by `@click` event way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **store.js**

- changed the carBrand default to ''
- added Mutation `clearFilter`
- added Getter `isActiveFilter`

**update**

- remove `carBrand` from state
- replaced by `selectedCars` that is an array
- removed mutation about `carBrand`
- added mutation `addCarSelection` `removeCarSelection`
- `filteredCars` return selectedCars array if contains cars, otherwise `cars` state
- added `isSelectedCar` to check if a car is in the selection

*`carFilter` function from filter.js is no longer needed.*

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    cars: [
      { name: "AUDI" },
      { name: "BMW" },
      { name: "MERCEDES" },
      { name: "HONDA" },
      { name: "TOYOTA" }
    ],
    selectedCars: []
  },
  mutations: {
    addCarSelection(state, car) {
      state.selectedCars.push(car);
    },
    removeCarSelection(state, car) {
      state.selectedCars = state.selectedCars.filter(r => r.name !== car.name);
    }
  },
  getters: {
    filteredCars: state => {
      if (state.selectedCars.length !== 0) {
        // There's selected cars, return filtered
        return state.selectedCars;
      } else {
        return state.cars;
      }
    },
    isSelectedCar: state => car => {
      return state.selectedCars.some(r => r.name === car.name);
    }
  }
});
```

In the **App.vue**

- added method `filterCars` (moved from computed property `searchText`)
- added method `clearFilter`

**update**

- removed `filterCars` and 'clearFilter' method and mapped new mutation and getters from store

```
  methods: {
    addCarSelection(car) {
      this.$store.commit("addCarSelection", car);
    },
    removeCarSelection(car) {
      this.$store.commit("removeCarSelection", car);
    },
    isSelectedCar(car) {
      return this.$store.getters.isSelectedCar(car)
    },
 }
```

- added `isFilterActive()` computed property

**update**

- removed `isFilterActive()` and `searchText` from computed property

```
  computed: {
    cars() {
      return this.$store.getters.filteredCars;
    },
},
```

**update**

- Changed the Template code to manage @click event to add car or remove car from selection
- boxes always show cars available, if `isSelectedCar` toggle between add or remove function.
- List show selected cars if presents otherwise the full car catalog.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div class="boxes" :key="index" v-for="(item, index) in cars">
      <div
        v-if="!isSelectedCar(item)"
        style="cursor:pointer"
        @click="addCarSelection(item)"
      >{{item.name}}</div>
      <div v-else style="cursor:pointer;" @click="removeCarSelection(item)">
        {{item.name}}
        <small>[x]</small>
      </div>
    </div>
    <List/>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Updated** version is available in this sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/filtering-3ej7d

Comment: thank you so much. it's so close to what, I wanted. But if I select one, then the others select options are disappearing. what if I wanted to select more than one? I don't want other select options disappear, so I can update the filter... is it possible to do that?

Comment: Code updated implementing an array with selected cars instead of filter. Is what you need?